# How do I access Augmented Image's getIndex from the Node.java file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arcore, sceneform

I have added a few different images to my imgdb file and these are being detected perfectly by arcore sceneform. However, I want to display a different 3D object for every image that is in the imgdb file. I believe this is possible using the getIndex function, but I do not know how to use the same since I am a rookie.

In the below code, how do I assign the index of the currently detected image to the variable 'value'?

```
public class AugmentedImageNode extends AnchorNode {

  private static final String TAG = "AugmentedImageNode";

  // The augmented image represented by this node.
  private AugmentedImage image;

 private static CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable> ulCorner;


   public AugmentedImageNode(Context context) {

          if (value == 0) {
              // Upon construction, start loading the models for the corners of the frame.
              if (ulCorner == null) {
                  ulCorner =
                          ModelRenderable.builder()
                                  .setSource(context, Uri.parse("models/tinker.sfb"))
                                  //.setSource(context, Uri.parse("models/borderfence-small2.sfb"))
                                  .build();
                   }
          }

          if (value == 1) {
              // Upon construction, start loading the models for the corners of the frame.
              if (ulCorner == null) {
                  ulCorner =
                          ModelRenderable.builder()
                                  .setSource(context, Uri.parse("models/borderfence-small.sfb"))
                                  //.setSource(context, Uri.parse("models/borderfence-small2.sfb"))
                                  .build();
              }
          }

      }

  /**
   * Called when the AugmentedImage is detected and should be rendered. A Sceneform node tree is
   * created based on an Anchor created from the image. The corners are then positioned based on the
   * extents of the image. There is no need to worry about world coordinates since everything is
   * relative to the center of the image, which is the parent node of the corners.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings({"AndroidApiChecker", "FutureReturnValueIgnored"})
  public void setImage(AugmentedImage image) {
    this.image = image;

    // If any of the models are not loaded, then recurse when all are loaded.
    if (!ulCorner.isDone())// || !urCorner.isDone() || !llCorner.isDone() || !lrCorner.isDone())
      {
      CompletableFuture.allOf(ulCorner)//, urCorner, llCorner, lrCorner)
          .thenAccept((Void aVoid) -> setImage(image))
          .exceptionally(
              throwable -> {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception loading", throwable);
                return null;
              });
    }

    // Set the anchor based on the center of the image.
    setAnchor(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose()));

    // Make the 4 corner nodes.
    Vector3 localPosition = new Vector3();
    Node cornerNode;

    // Upper left corner.
    //localPosition.set(-0.5f * image.getExtentX(), 0.0f, -0.5f * image.getExtentZ());
    localPosition.set(-0.0f * image.getExtentX(), 0.1f, +0.5f * image.getExtentZ());
    cornerNode = new Node();
    cornerNode.setParent(this);
    cornerNode.setLocalPosition(localPosition);
    cornerNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(-1f, 0, 0), 90f));
    cornerNode.setRenderable(ulCorner.getNow(null));

  }

    private void setLocalRotation() {
    }

    public AugmentedImage getImage() {
    return image;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getIndex()` function that's available for AugmentedImage.

> #### public int getIndex ()
>
> Returns the zero-based positional index of this augmented image from its originating image database.
>
> This index serves as the unique identifier for the image in the database.

For further reading, refer to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/arcore/reference/com/google/ar/core/AugmentedImage) or the [Sceneform AugmentedImage Sample](https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/augmentedimage/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/sceneform/samples/augmentedimage/AugmentedImageActivity.java#L85).

Comment: Hi, mark the answer as correct if it works(or feel free to add your own answer if the issue was something else), cheers.